# How to access data of Django ManyToMany Field?

Tags: python, django

I want to Create a Like Functionality in Home page of my Social media Website. I am using ManyToManyField for Storing Likes on Particular post as shown in models.py. In my home page I have list of Posts and I want to check weather a Posts in already Liked by Current Logged in User or not.

In my views.py I am using

```
post = Posts.objects.filter('likes')
if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
```

models.py

```
class Posts(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False)
content = models.CharField(max_length=15000,
                           help_text="Write Your thought here...")
likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
post = Posts.objects.filter('likes')
print('Thats just Test', post)
if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
    print("Already Exixts")
    is_liked = False
context = {
    'all_posts': all_posts,
    'is_liked': is_liked,
}
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

hometemplte.html: (Only Like Button)

```
<form action="{% url 'like_post' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% if is_liked %}
              <button type="submit" name="like" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn upvote liked">Liked</button>
            {% else %}
              <button type="submit" name="like" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn upvote">Upvote</button>
            {% endif %}
          </form>
```

Comment: Do you want to check a particular post has been liked by the user? or do you want the list of posts liked by the user?

Comment: @PranshTiwari I want to check weather a Particular Post is liked by User or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get data of the `ManyToMany` field, for backwards mapping you need to use `related_name` parameter while declaring the model.

So your attribute will be:

```
likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='likes')
```

Your query to check if the particular post has been liked by the user or not is:

```
post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
```

**Update**

The issue in your case is you are retrieving multiple posts in a single line:

`Posts.objects.filter('likes')`, which returns a query set.
You need to fetch a particular post and then check if the user likes the post or not.

`post = Posts.objects.all()[0]` will not throw any error.

Comment: I am getting Value Error at line `post = Posts.objects.filter('likes')` in views.py

Comment: This only checks weather first post has liked by current user or not. How to check for all users in generic way?

Comment: post = Posts.objects.all()[0] was just example. You need to fetch individual Posts according to your logic, or iterate based on certain criteria and check if it has been liked by the signed in user or not.

Comment: Not yet... I still didn't find any way to iterate over the `post` and check weather current user had liked it or not. Now I am trying to Solve it through Templates.But Thank you for Your Response